# numpy.memmap not able to handle very big data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, out-of-memory, bigdata

I need to hold a very large vector in memory, about 10**8 in size, and I need a fast random access to it.
I tried to use numpy.memmap, but encountered the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars bytes = long(offset + size*_dbytes)

fid.seek(bytes - 1, 0): [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

It seems that the memmap is using a long and my vector length is too big.

Is there a way to overcome this and use memmap? or maybe there is a good alternative?

Thanks

Comment: https://dask.org .

Comment: something about your description doesn't make sense. A signed `long` is at least 32 bytes, and the largest number it can store is slightly larger than `2*10**9`. If the size of your array is on the order of `10**8`, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The exact size of 10 ** 8 * 4 and I use float64 at each cell, so it sums up to bigger then long 10 ** 9.

Comment: @B.M. Thanks for the suggestion, I checked Dask arrays but it seems they are immutable and thus not fit for my purpose, does Dask offer a mutable kind of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Easy solution

It sounds like you're using a 32-bit version of Python (I also assume you're running on Windows). From the [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) docs:

> Memory-mapped files cannot be larger than 2GB on 32-bit systems.

So the simple solution to your problem is to just upgrade your Python install to 64-bit.

If your CPU was manufactured sometime in that last decade, it should be possible to upgrade to 64-bit Python.

## Alternatives

So long as your Python is 32-bit, working with arrays larger than 2 GB is never going to be easy or straightforward. Your only real option is to split the array up into pieces no larger than 2 GB at the time you originally create it/write it out to disk. You would then operate on each piece independently.

Also, you'd still have to use `numpy.memmap` with each piece, since Python itself will run out of memory otherwise.

## Heavy duty alternatives

If handling these kinds of large arrays is something you have to do a lot of on a regular basis, you should consider switching your code/workflow over one of the big data frameworks. There's a whole bunch of them available for Python now. I've used [Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html) extensively before, and it's pretty easy to use (though requires a bunch of set up). In the comments B. M. mentions [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/why.html), another such big data framework.

Though if this is just a one off task, it's probably not worth the trouble to spin up one of these frameworks.